# How to include apostrophe in character set for REGEXP_SUBSTR()

Tags: sql, regex, posix, db2-400

The IBM i implementation of regex uses apostrophes (instead of e.g. slashes) to delimit a regex string, i.e.:

```
... where REGEXP_SUBSTR(MYFIELD,'myregex_expression')
```

If I try to use an apostrophe inside a [group] within the expression, it always errors - presumably thinking I am giving a closing quote. I have tried:
- escaping it: \'
- doubling it: '' (and tripling)

No joy. I cannot find anything relevant in the IBM SQL manual or by google search.

I really need this to, for instance, allow names like O'Leary.

Comment: Try the usual workaround: `\x27` (the hex `\xXX` notation)

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm#rbafzregexp_like__regexp_likecontrol (@WiktorStribiżew comment sounds plausible to me from these docs)

Comment: Thank you - I'll try it.

Comment: Please let know if it works, and also try changing delimiter quotes, e.g. `"myregex_'_expression"`

Comment: Yes, it does work, thank you. I'll update the main body with some additional info arising from my experimentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single quote can be defined with the `\x27` notation:

```
^[A-Z0-9_+\x27-]+
          ^^^^
```

Note that when you use a hyphen in the character class/bracket expression, when used in between some chars it forms a *range* between those symbols. When you used `^[A-Z0-9_\+-\x27]+` you defined a range between `+` and `'`, which is an invalid range as the `+` comes after `'` in the Unicode table.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Wiktor Stribizew for the answer in his comment.

There are a couple of "gotchas" for anyone who might land on this question with the same problem. The first is that you have to give the (presumably Unicode) hex value rather than the EBCDIC value that you would use, e.g. in ordinary interactive SQL on the IBM i. So in this case it really is \x27 and not \x7D for an apostrophe. Presumably this is because the REGEXP_ ... functions are working through Unicode even for EBCDIC data.

The second thing is that it would seem that the hex value cannot be the last one in the set. So this works:

```
^[A-Z0-9_\+\x27-]+ ... etc.
```

But this doesn't

```
^[A-Z0-9_\+-\x27]+ ... etc.
```

I don't know how to highlight text within a code sample, so I draw your attention to the fact that the hyphen is last in the first sample and second-to-last in the second sample.

If anyone knows why it has to not be last, I'd be interested to know. [edit: see Wiktor's answer for the reason]

btw, using double quotes as the string delimiter with an apostrophe in the set didn't work in this context.

Comment: It certainly was useful. Saved me a lot of fruitless searching.